# Use rest api call to create a new jenkins slave using python

Tags: python, jenkins

I am automating our jenkins slave creation process using python and i am designing a function that takes the slave name and the json file as input and creates a new jenkins slave in my jenkins instance.

i came across one jenkins documentation which talks about this and i have a working bash script to do this. But my requirement is a python script. My bash script works but when i convert it to python it does not. Can someone help me out here.

Here are both my `bash` and `python` scripts.

```
#!/bin/bash

export JENKINS_URL=https://jenkins.domain.com
export JENKINS_USER=<user>
export JENKINS_API_TOKEN=<api>
export NODE_NAME=testnode_sep17
export JSON_OBJECT="{ 'name':+'${NODE_NAME}',+'nodeDescription':+'Linux+slave',+'numExecutors':+'5',+'remoteFS':+'/home/jenkins/agent',+'labelString':+'SLAVE-DOCKER+linux',+'mode':+'EXCLUSIVE',+'':+['hudson.slaves.JNLPLauncher',+'hudson.slaves.RetentionStrategy\$Always'],+'launcher':+{'stapler-class':+'hudson.slaves.JNLPLauncher',+'\$class':+'hudson.slaves.JNLPLauncher',+'workDirSettings':+{'disabled':+true,+'workDirPath':+'',+'internalDir':+'remoting',+'failIfWorkDirIsMissing':+false},+'tunnel':+'',+'vmargs':+'-Xmx1024m'},+'retentionStrategy':+{'stapler-class':+'hudson.slaves.RetentionStrategy\$Always',+'\$class':+'hudson.slaves.RetentionStrategy\$Always'},+'nodeProperties':+{'stapler-class-bag':+'true',+'hudson-slaves-EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty':+{'env':+[{'key':+'JAVA_HOME',+'value':+'/docker-java-home'},+{'key':+'JENKINS_HOME',+'value':+'/home/jenkins'}]},+'hudson-tools-ToolLocationNodeProperty':+{'locations':+[{'key':+'hudson.plugins.git.GitTool\$DescriptorImpl@Default',+'home':+'/usr/bin/git'},+{'key':+'hudson.model.JDK\$DescriptorImpl@JAVA-8',+'home':+'/usr/bin/java'},+{'key':+'hudson.tasks.Maven\$MavenInstallation\$DescriptorImpl@MAVEN-3.5.2',+'home':+'/usr/bin/mvn'}]}}}"
curl -L -s -o /dev/null -v -k -w "%{http_code}" -u "${JENKINS_USER}:${JENKINS_API_TOKEN}" -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST -d "json=${JSON_OBJECT}" "${JENKINS_URL}/computer/doCreateItem?name=${NODE_NAME}&type=hudson.slaves.DumbSlave"
```

and here is the python script

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}

params = (
    ('name', 'test_sep17_TBR'),
    ('type', 'hudson.slaves.DumbSlave'),
)

#data = {
 # 'json': 'file.json'
#}
data = open('my_file.json', 'rb').read()

response = requests.post('http://jenkins.domain.com/computer/doCreateItem', headers=headers, params=params, data=data, verify=False, auth=('user', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'))
print(response.text)
```

my_file.json has the following data

```
{ 'name':+'${NODE_NAME}',+'nodeDescription':+'Linux+slave',+'numExecutors':+'5',+'remoteFS':+'/home/jenkins/agent',+'labelString':+'SLAVE-DOCKER+linux',+'mode':+'EXCLUSIVE',+'':+['hudson.slaves.JNLPLauncher',+'hudson.slaves.RetentionStrategy\$Always'],+'launcher':+{'stapler-class':+'hudson.slaves.JNLPLauncher',+'\$class':+'hudson.slaves.JNLPLauncher',+'workDirSettings':+{'disabled':+true,+'workDirPath':+'',+'internalDir':+'remoting',+'failIfWorkDirIsMissing':+false},+'tunnel':+'',+'vmargs':+'-Xmx1024m'},+'retentionStrategy':+{'stapler-class':+'hudson.slaves.RetentionStrategy\$Always',+'\$class':+'hudson.slaves.RetentionStrategy\$Always'},+'nodeProperties':+{'stapler-class-bag':+'true',+'hudson-slaves-EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty':+{'env':+[{'key':+'JAVA_HOME',+'value':+'/docker-java-home'},+{'key':+'JENKINS_HOME',+'value':+'/home/jenkins'}]},+'hudson-tools-ToolLocationNodeProperty':+{'locations':+[{'key':+'hudson.plugins.git.GitTool\$DescriptorImpl@Default',+'home':+'/usr/bin/git'},+{'key':+'hudson.model.JDK\$DescriptorImpl@JAVA-8',+'home':+'/usr/bin/java'},+{'key':+'hudson.tasks.Maven\$MavenInstallation\$DescriptorImpl@MAVEN-3.5.2',+'home':+'/usr/bin/mvn'}]}}}
```

when i run the bash script, the slave gets created.
But when i run my python scrit, the error that i get is

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Error 400 This page expects a form submission</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 400</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /computer/doCreateItem. Reason:
<pre>    This page expects a form submission</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>

</body>
</html>
```

Edit: i can use python jenkins module to create the slave, but i do not want to use that

Comment: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003896171-Creating-node-with-the-REST-API might help

Comment: this talks about bash, i want it in python

Comment: I would recommend familiarizing yourself with https://curl.haxx.se/ and https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/

Answer (score 1):

After spending several hours, I found what we both missed:

> -d "json=${JSON_OBJECT}"

Which means it's posting a string, so in python you need:

```
requests.post(url, data=f'json={json.dumps(postdata)}', headers=headers)
```